# getting Must trace apex_code at finest when checking the variable panel

Tags: apex, debugging, debug-logs, apex-variable, apex-debugger

I have already set the apex debug level at FINEST but still when I check the variable panel I still see the message **must trace APEX_CODE at Finest** can someone please suggest on the same?

Below is the screenshot of my debug settings in developer edition.

[image]

[image]

Below is the variable panel in the developer console
[image]

**I Have tried the same on production, sandbox and developer edition but still I get the same message can anyone please suggest?**

Comment: Can you screenshot your debug settings?

Comment: Are you talking about using Checkpoints in the Developer Console, the old, paid apex debugger in Eclipse, or the Apex Replay Debugger in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Thank you so much for responding I have updated my question with the screenshots.

Comment: That might just be for the `SFDC_DevConsole` settings but not the actual User settings for your session.  Check those settings as well (which usually sit above what you're showing in the first screenshot)

Comment: Hi @BrianMiller I have again updated my question with more detailed screenshots

Comment: Are you running Apex code?  Is it being generated from a VF page?  Testing trigger code?  Not sure what the issue could be right now, very strange

Comment: I am executing a class method from the anonymous window

Comment: It could be an issue running it from a Sandbox.  I don't think you will see the same issue in production

Comment: I am in developer edition nether sandbox nor production

Answer (score 0):

While having log panels up, make sure Debug only is unchecked.  That way you can view the full execution log.  To check variables, look at the event column, and wherever you see VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT, click on each one and and the variables panel will update accordingly.